# Is it possible to update the backup android application file from playstore?

Tags: applications

Is it possible to update android apk files saved on sdcard but are not installed. any application or any method if it is possible.

**Edit**
I just want upgrade the version of these files because in playstore only installed files can be upgraded.

Comment: "*Is it possible to update android apk files saved on sdcard but are not installed*" -- what are you attempting to update if the app is not installed? Are you talking about modding? What is your final goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible or not?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135070). I  find the current question beyond salvation so I recommend this be deleted than be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

An `.apk` file already contains a certain version of an application. You can't *update* it since updating already means installation of a higher version `.apk`.