# Is it possible or not?

Tags: applications

My question goes like this.
As we know playstore has great no. of applications and we need to use many of them. but if we install many apps at a time phone becomes too slow. so we install apps only when required and later remove them but we store all backups on sdcard.

now for eg. i have backup of an app say mx player and its version is 8.4.32 but in playstore current version is 9... and other backups also have higher versions in playstore. is there any app or way to update all the backup file  to current version available in playstore.

Comment: Set Play Store to auto update your apps, install Titanium Backup Pro and configure it to schedule backup of those apps after a certain interval.

Comment: but playstore only upgrades installed files. I am asking about update of offline backup files.

Comment: Didn't I say Titanium Backup Pro to backup the currently installed apps? It should make an updated backup of app with  versions currently available in Play Store. // If your only concern is to take backup of APK files of currently installed and well updated apps, then you can use my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/132524/96277). Use it with the intent `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED`. I've my device setup to automatically copy APK file of an app whenever an app is installed or updated.

Comment: @Firelord Guess you've missed the point of OP's question. Wanted solution is: 1) backup, **2) uninstall,** 3) have the *backup* updated whenever an update becomes available – but without the app being actually installed.

Comment: @UmeshNB your app would be updated as soon as you re-install it. AFAIK there's no way to have those backups updated without the app being installed.